# ASP.net rijndael decrypt - Length of data to decrypt

Tags: asp.net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, rijndael

A lot of items I've found so far have been a bit vague or ... unspecific so I'm hoping to get an answer.

I've got two little methods - easy ones that look as such...

```
    private const string initVector = "1234567890123456";
    private const string SaltValue = "ThisIsMySaltValue";
    private const int KeySize = 256;

    public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt)
    {
        var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged {KeySize = KeySize};
        var salt = SaltValue.ToByteArray();
        var vector = initVector.ToByteArray();

        var rfcBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(vector, salt, 2);
        var key = rfcBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize/8);

        ICryptoTransform encrypt = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }


    public static string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt)
    {
        var vector = initVector.ToByteArray();
        var salt = SaltValue.ToByteArray();
        var encrypted = textToDecrypt.ToByteArray();

        var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged {KeySize = KeySize};

        var rfcBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(vector, salt, 2);
        var key = rfcBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize/8);

        var decrypt = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);

        var stream = new MemoryStream(encrypted);
        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[textToDecrypt.Length];

        var decryptedLength = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

        var plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, decryptedLength);
        return plainText;
    }
```

Unit Test looks something like this ...

```
    [Test]
    public void JustTestingThisOut()
    {
        var encryptMe = "SomethingToEncrypt";
        string result = encryptMe.ConvertToEncrypted();
        result.ShouldNotEqual(encryptMe);
        string backToReadAble = result.ConvertToDecrpted();
        backToReadAble.ShouldEqual(encryptMe);
    }
```

ToByteArray just does a return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toByte); and my test string is simple - "SomethingToEncrypt".  I've went down the rabbit hole of finding [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=325676) thinking that might have been the problem (Convert.ToBase64String and Convert.FromBase64String) that doesn't seem to make any difference.  As for the error ...

> TestCase
>   'Tests.Encryption.EncryptionUnitTests.JustTestingThisOut'
>   failed:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>   : Length of the data to decrypt is
>   invalid.  at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
>   inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32
>   inputCount)

I have the FlushFinalBlock() in there, and I THOUGHT that'd do it, but ...nope, makes no difference as well.  Any ideas? Things to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encrypting, you first write `data` to `stream`, then you wrap `stream` with a `CryptoStream` and write `data` again, this time with encryption. Why? The decryption fails because the first thing it encounters is unencrypted data.

Print the value of the ciphertext *before* base64 encoding to verify this. You should see the plaintext followed by a bunch of gobbledygook that is the ciphertext.

Also, you are using the initialization vector as a password. They are definitely not the same thing, and using it like this will compromise security.

Comment: I've seen that at some point -- the diamond question marks after the text.  Let me see if I can't get it back to that.

regarding the IV -- yea, I know, I'm just trying to get it to work first.  I have a private password value for testing right now that looks something like ... private const string password = "AreYouTellingMeThatAThreeOunceBirdCanCarryAOnePoundCoconut?"; :-)

Comment: yep, yanking that one line -- stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); and it works.  Now to wire up the fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see how this will work as jeriley suggests since in the decrypt function you do

`var encrypted = textToDecrypt.ToByteArray();`

Here textToDecrypt is a base64 string. You first have to convert the base64 back to ordinary bytes which you can then use to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You have an intermittent bug lurking in your code...

You should never use any of the System.Text.Encoding classes for cipher text. You *will* experience intermittent errors.  You should use Base64 encoding and the System.Convert class methods.

1. To obtain an encrypted string from an encrypted byte[], you should use:

`Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] bytes)`

1. To obtain a a raw byte[] from a string to be encrypted, you should use:

`Convert.FromBase64String(string data)`

One additional note is that you'll need to have `FlushFinalBlock()` when doing the encryption or it won't get padded correctly.

For additional info, please refer to MS Security guru Shawn Fanning's post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/11/10/491431.aspx